# TDD - Making assertions about C# Expression trees

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, linq, mocking

How would you unit test the PerformUpdate method in the sample below? This is a (very) simplified version of some code that performs updates against a database where the schema is dynamic and represented by the fields collection.

EDIT: If it is not clear what I am asking, I would like to know how different developers would approach testing\mocking this code from a TDD perspective. For example, what tests would you write, what would you mock, how would you verify method calls are made with the right arguments?

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IEfRepository<Field> Fields { get; }
}

public class UpdateService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    private IDataUpdater dataService;

    public Activity PerformUpdate(App app, IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        var fields = this.unitOfWork.Fields.FindWhere(o => o.App.Identifier == app.Identifier);
        var activity = this.dataService.PerformUpdate(fields, data);

        return activity;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need more info. What is the purpose of the method, a bit of context/background would help. I mean I do understand what the code does, but I can't understand why

Comment: Sure thing. This is a (very) simplified version of some code that performs updates against a database where the schema is dynamic and represented by the fields collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different parts to be tested here. Ultimately my answer is the same regardless of the specific portion of the code. The validity of each entities method should be tested separately as it's own concern (I'm sure your doing this anyway).

In terms of testing say the `PerformUpdate` method, your best bet here is to mock / stub both the `IUnitOfWork` and `IDataUpdater`. In each case the mock / stubs would make an assumption (good data and bad data). Simply query these after they are called to confirm the validity of the call.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would mock the fields repository and validate that the FindWhere method was called with the correct arguments?

Comment: Or some alternative way of verifying the fields passed to dataservice.PerformUpdate.

Comment: Sure, can you tell me what assemblies you have for each object? I can pull them and mock it out then

Comment: I'm not sure what more you need here? You can assume that IDataService just has one member matching the arguments seen in the example.

Comment: I'm more interested in Fields and IEFRepository so I can mock them.

Comment: Ultimately what I intend to do is fake IEFRepository with a few fields that I know match the Identifier and confirm each one was passed to the IDataService.

Comment: That's cool, that description of the approach is enough. I could change the expression and the tests would still pass though... how would you defend against this?

Comment: You couldn't as both are mocked / stubbed I would be expecting specific fields. Any change that changes the fields returned would break the test. Any change that does not change the fields can be considered an alternate implementation.

Comment: Ok, now we are almost there! How would you create a mock that responded to a given expression?

Comment: I wouldn't. The contract for find where states that it will give you what you ask for. It is not up to the test to validate the data is there, only that you respond correctly to it not being there. To clarify, you are testing the data. You should be testing your response to either having or not having the expected data.

Comment: So you would not test what we are asking for?

Comment: My point is, if we somehow end up with fields from another client's app, this could be completely catastrophic, and at the moment prevent this is really the sole purpose of this class.

Comment: Correct. but that is not the fault of the code. My question to you would be why are you allowing fields from two different domains to be queried like that. Your problem is you are worried that the data will not be correctly filtered. I would argue that you should never be in a situation were this is a possibility. In your case above, PerformUpdate should take in app and validate against the identifier if your are allowing such wide queries.

Comment: Or create a method to encapsulate this FindByApp(App app Func<>)

Comment: I think you are missing the point. It doesn't matter how far down to the metal you push this check, it still has to be made at some point. If I am not testing it here then I will have to do it somewhere else so the problem still exists.

Comment: @Roysvork I think what @McDonnellDean means is that a unit test for `UpdateService` shouldn't test the correctness of objects it collaborates with (`Fields.FindWhere()`). This is precisely what mocks and stubs are for - remove your neighbor's correctness from the equation. Just test that you send them the right messages and can handle their answers. And if `Fields.FindWhere()` is code you wrote, then yes, you'll have to test it, but somewhere else.

Comment: We had a further discussion about this via chat. I think we came to a conclusion but I will let @Roysvork confirm. Ultimately it came down to using a manual Mock or Stub, by using this he is free to add whatever validation he needs rather than being limited by a given Mocking tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an unhelpful answer for you :)

I'd probably not unit test this, and would create a more behavioural component-level test with a few complex Fakes.

Wondering how you test a particular implementation seems like a smell to me - you should be asking 'how would I develop an implementation to fulfil this requirement?'

Comment: This is not the purpose of this question :) Regardless of how this is structured, at some point I will need test that I am supplying the correct fields and it is that verification which is at the end of this rabbit hole :)